# how to run apache superset in dev mode on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-ec2, apache-superset

I have developed a plugin for the apache superset,for which I have followed the following tutorial https://preset.io/blog/2020-07-02-hello-world/

In this tutorial the setup only works for development environment. So I need to run the backend server and frontend server separately using these commands.

for backend:
`superset run -p 8088 -h 0.0.0.0 --with-threads --reload --debugger`

for frontend:
`npm run dev-server`

In inboud rules in the security group for my EC2 instance, I have set the inbound rules to custom tcp where I have allowed the traffic for port 9000, 8088.

however I am unable to ping publicDNS of EC2:9000
this is not the case when I ping publicDNS of EC2:8088

Answer (score 0):

turns out if we edit the webpack.config.js file and add an additional parameter for for host by passing `devserverHost = '0.0.0.0'` and then replacing the 'localhost' with ${devserverHost} solves the problem, additionally this also has to be done for the webpack.proxy.config.js file